# ESP32 touch sensor for deep sleep

Tags: c++, bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32, arduino-ide

I'm trying to wake up my esp32 to receive data through Bluetooth in nRF Connect, but I have no value of temperature, hummidity and pressure. I don't know why I don't see anything, because my sensors(DHT22 and BMP280) are corectly connected and they transmit good values in serial monitor, but in application value field is empty.I tried to put in characteristics in callback function or in setup, but the same problem, empty value. What is the problem? Can anyone to advice me?
I attach my code below. Thanks in advance!

```
#include <BLEDevice.h>
#include <BLEServer.h>
#include <BLEUtils.h>
//#include <BLE2902.h>
#include "DHT.h"
//#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_BMP280.h>
#include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <HTTPClient.h>

  

BLEServer* pServer = NULL;
BLECharacteristic* temp_pCharacteristic = NULL;
BLECharacteristic* hum_pCharacteristic = NULL;
BLECharacteristic* pres_pCharacteristic = NULL;

bool deviceConnected = false;
bool oldDeviceConnected = false;

 #define DHTPIN 4            // Digital pin connected to the DHT sensor
 #define DHTTYPE DHT22       // DHT 22  (AM2302), AM2321
 DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);

 Adafruit_BMP280 bmp;         // Instantiate (create) a BMP280 object and set-up for I2C operation


  #define Threshold 40 /* Greater the value, more the sensitivity */



  RTC_DATA_ATTR int bootCount = 0;
  touch_pad_t touchPin;

 class MyServerCallbacks: public BLEServerCallbacks {
     void onConnect(BLEServer* pServer) {
        deviceConnected = true;
  };

    void onDisconnect(BLEServer* pServer) {
       deviceConnected = false;
   }
  };

void init_sensors(){
   dht.begin(); 

   bool status;
   status = bmp.begin(0x76);

   if (!status) {
     Serial.println("Could not find a valid BMP280 sensor, check wiring!");
     while (1);
  }

 }

 /*
 Method to print the reason by which ESP32
 has been awaken from sleep
 */
void print_wakeup_reason(){
   esp_sleep_wakeup_cause_t wakeup_reason;

   wakeup_reason = esp_sleep_get_wakeup_cause();

   switch(wakeup_reason)
   {
     case ESP_SLEEP_WAKEUP_EXT0 : Serial.println("Wakeup caused by external signal using RTC_IO"); 
     break;
     case ESP_SLEEP_WAKEUP_EXT1 : Serial.println("Wakeup caused by external signal using RTC_CNTL"); 
     break;
     case ESP_SLEEP_WAKEUP_TIMER : Serial.println("Wakeup caused by timer"); break;
     case ESP_SLEEP_WAKEUP_TOUCHPAD : Serial.println("Wakeup caused by touchpad"); break;
     case ESP_SLEEP_WAKEUP_ULP : Serial.println("Wakeup caused by ULP program"); break;
     default : Serial.printf("Wakeup was not caused by deep sleep: %d\n",wakeup_reason); break;
    }
 }

 /*
 Method to print the touchpad by which ESP32
 has been awaken from sleep
 */
void print_wakeup_touchpad(){
  touchPin = esp_sleep_get_touchpad_wakeup_status();

  switch(touchPin)
 {
case 0  : Serial.println("Touch detected on GPIO 4"); break;
case 1  : Serial.println("Touch detected on GPIO 0"); break;
case 2  : Serial.println("Touch detected on GPIO 2"); break;
case 3  : Serial.println("Touch detected on GPIO 15"); break;
case 4  : Serial.println("Touch detected on GPIO 13"); break;
case 5  : Serial.println("Touch detected on GPIO 12"); break;
case 6  : Serial.println("Touch detected on GPIO 14"); break;
case 7  : Serial.println("Touch detected on GPIO 27"); break;
case 8  : Serial.println("Touch detected on GPIO 33"); break;
case 9  : Serial.println("Touch detected on GPIO 32"); break;
default : Serial.println("Wakeup not by touchpad"); break;
 }
  }

  void callback(){
     //placeholder callback function
     // notify changed value
    /* init_sensors();
    if (deviceConnected){ 
        uint32_t t = dht.readTemperature();
        uint32_t h = dht.readHumidity();
        uint32_t p = bmp.readPressure();
    
        temp_pCharacteristic->setValue(t);
        temp_pCharacteristic->notify();

        hum_pCharacteristic->setValue(h);
        hum_pCharacteristic->notify();

        pres_pCharacteristic->setValue(p);
        pres_pCharacteristic->notify();
    
        delay(2000); // bluetooth stack will go into congestion, if too many packets are sent, in 6 
        hours test i was able to go as low as 3ms
     }  */
   }

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(115200);

  //Take some time to open up the Serial Monitor
    
   init_sensors(); //apelarea functiei pentru configurarea senzorilor
   delay(2000);
   //   float temp = dht.readTemperature();
   // float hum = dht.readHumidity();
   // float pres = bmp.readPressure();


   // Create the BLE Device
   BLEDevice::init("T");

   // Create the BLE Server
   pServer = BLEDevice::createServer();
   pServer->setCallbacks(new MyServerCallbacks());

   // Create the BLE Service
   BLEService *pService = pServer->createService(BLEUUID((uint16_t)0x181A));

   // Create a BLE Characteristic
   temp_pCharacteristic = pService->createCharacteristic(
                          BLEUUID((uint16_t)0x2A6E),
                          BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_READ   |
                          BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_WRITE  |
                          BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_NOTIFY |
                          BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_INDICATE
                          );


   hum_pCharacteristic = pService->createCharacteristic(
                         BLEUUID((uint16_t)0x2A6F),
                         BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_READ   |
                         BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_WRITE  |
                         BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_NOTIFY |
                         BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_INDICATE
                         );




  pres_pCharacteristic = pService->createCharacteristic(
                         BLEUUID((uint16_t)0x2A6D),
                         BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_READ   |
                         BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_WRITE  |
                         BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_NOTIFY |
                         BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_INDICATE
                         );


   // Create a BLE Descriptor
   //hum_pCharacteristic->addDescriptor(new BLE2902());

   // Start the service
   pService->start();

   // Start advertising
   BLEAdvertising *pAdvertising = BLEDevice::getAdvertising();
   pAdvertising->addServiceUUID(BLEUUID((uint16_t)0x181A));
   pAdvertising->setScanResponse(false);
   pAdvertising->setMinPreferred(0x0);  // set value to 0x00 to not advertise this parameter
   BLEDevice::startAdvertising();
   Serial.println("Waiting a client connection to notify...");


    //Increment boot number and print it every reboot
    ++bootCount;
    Serial.println("Boot number: " + String(bootCount));

    //Print the wakeup reason for ESP32 and touchpad too
    print_wakeup_reason();
    print_wakeup_touchpad();

   //Setup interrupt on Touch Pad 3 (GPIO15)
   touchAttachInterrupt(T3, callback, Threshold);
  //init_sensors();
  if (deviceConnected){ 
    float t = dht.readTemperature(true);
    float h = dht.readHumidity(true);
    float p = bmp.readPressure();
    
    char tStr[10];
    char hStr[10];
    char pStr[10];
    
    sprintf(tStr, "%4.4f", t);
    sprintf(hStr, "%4.4f", h);
    sprintf(pStr, "%4.4f", p);
    
    temp_pCharacteristic->setValue(tStr);
    temp_pCharacteristic->notify();

    hum_pCharacteristic->setValue(hStr);
    hum_pCharacteristic->notify();

    pres_pCharacteristic->setValue(pStr);
    pres_pCharacteristic->notify();
    
   delay(2000); // bluetooth stack will go into congestion, if too many packets are sent, in 6 hours 
   test i was able to go as low as 3ms
  }

 //delay(2000);
//Serial.println("Temperature: ");
//Serial.print(temp);
//Serial.println("Hummidity: ");
//Serial.print(hum);
//Serial.println("Atmospheric Pressure: ");
//Serial.print(pres);


  delay(30000);   

  //Configure Touchpad as wakeup source
  esp_sleep_enable_touchpad_wakeup();

   //Go to sleep now
  Serial.println("Going to sleep now");
  esp_deep_sleep_start();
  Serial.println("This will never be printed");
  }

void loop(){
   //This will never be reached
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

"value field is empty"

There is nothing in your code named anything like 'value field'.  Are you referring to

```
float t = dht.readTemperature(true);
```

If so, are you certain this code is executed?  Perhaps `deviceConnected` is never true?

You are depending on this being executed

```
 class MyServerCallbacks: public BLEServerCallbacks {
     void onConnect(BLEServer* pServer) {
        deviceConnected = true;
  };
```

This looks dodgy to me.  Shouldn't the method be public?  In any case, add a print statement to ensure this is actually running.

Comment: I tried to put  `deviceConnected`  true, but my callback function  never executes. I don't know what is wrong :(

Comment: Best guess: you have not correctly over-ridden the OnConnect method of the BLEServerCallbacks  base class.  Have another look at the instructions for doing so.  It seems dodgy to me that the methods in your specialized class are private.